# How to perform functions on unique values in dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data of about 5 million records that like in the image below
I need to get the max and average value for each id in a new data frame,so that each ID will have just one value

I am pretty new to python and programming and this group has been helpful but i don't seem to find related answer to this particular question.  Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? Take a look at [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dummy data
ids = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
values = [13,21,34,22,34,2,3,34,12,45,45,23,67,76,32,23,80]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ids, 'Values': values})

df = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Values': [min, max, np.mean]})  # group by on ID and calculate new columns min, max, mean for the values columns
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)  # get rid of the multilevel columns due to the grouping
df.reset_index()
```

**EDIT**: with thanks to ALollz for pointing out the following shortcut (avoiding the multilevel index):

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Values'].agg([min, max, np.mean])  # group by on ID and calculate new columns min, max, mean for the values columns
df.reset_index()
```

Let me know if any of the steps requires elaboration.

Comment: Since all aggregations are for a single column, you can agg the Series, which doesn't result in a MultiIndex for the columns: `df.groupby('ID')['Values'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])`

Comment: Excellent, missed that shortcut. Will edit it in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @RubenB I found the steps clear and the code worked perfectly